# remove combined IBaction without removing

Tags: xcode, swift, ibaction

I've created an IBaction by highlighting multiple buttons and drag to my code.

I really don't want all 3 buttons to do same, so deleted the IBaction in the code.

However, the actions still remains (see screen dump)

How can I remove the 'received action' without removing the buttons involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the storyboard / nib, what you have are *connections*. So go to each button's Connections inspector and delete the action there.

To delete an action, click the little X:

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, here I am struggling to find out how to add an image in my question, and I already have an answer.. I did see the connections inspector for the button, and the relations it has, but when I click on one of the connections, pressing DEL, deletes the whole button. How can I delete the connection only? (I want to show you what I have, but still don't know how to add an image).

Comment: Matt, That was toooo easy. I didn't see them as x's, but merely as bullet points. Thanks a lot. saves me re-creating put-ons, actions and outlets.   P.S. can you quickly explain how to insert screen dump or image in questions!!!!

Comment: You do not have enough rep to add images. You can post an image elsewhere and provide a link.

Comment: Done, I was pressing the arrow up, but that didn't work either. Need 15 points or something like that.  You've been very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by matt is correct but incomplete.   The complete procedure for Xcode Version 8.2.1 is described as below:

{1} Open Project Navigator/Area--typically displayed at the left side    then select "Main.storyboard" within the Project Navigator

{2} Open Utility Navigator/Area--typically displayed at the right side then select "Connections Inspector" as shown in matt's picture.

{3} click an Outlet or Action object (it could be a label, a text, an image, etc.) in the View Area--typically is in the middle.  This action will display the linked Outlet or Action object in the Utility Area at the left side

{4} Delete/remove the connection in the Connections Inspector as as shown in matt's picture.  The connection will disappear and the connection/link is removed

{5} Go back to Project Navigator then select the Swift code that contains the associated Outlet or Action object--typically it starts with @IBAction xxx.  Comment out or delete the related code and recompile/rebuild.

The above has been down routinely by our team with completed success.  The same procedure may work for previous Xcode revisions down to Version 6.